# jquery on click change body opacity

Tags: jquery, css

How can I change the body background color to be darker after I click on a button, something like the "lightbox" overlay effect.

I did it with jQuery UI animate:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('button').click(function(){

$('body').animate({
    backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)'
    });
    $('.popup').show();
});

});
```

Exmaple: http://jsfiddle.net/nb4s4vya/

But I would like to do that without the jQuery UI

Comment: You mean you want it to animate, or just change directly?

Answer (score 0):

As in like this?

$(body).css('background-color', '#000000');

Answer (score 0):

Use [CSS transition](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_transitions.asp) to animate it:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
$('button').click(function(){
    $('body').addClass('clickedbody');
    $('.popup').show();
}); 
});


$(document).mouseup(function (e)
{
    var container = $('.popup');
    if (!container.is(e.target) 
        && container.has(e.target).length === 0)
    {
        container.slideUp();
    }
});
```

```css
.clickedbody{
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  -webkit-transition: background-color ease 1s;
  transition: background-color ease 1s;
}
input[type="text"] { border:none; padding: 10px; background:#ffffff; }
input[type="submit"] { border:none; background:#F5DB02; color:#000; padding:10px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>    
    <button>GO</button>
    
    <div class="popup" style="display:none;">
        <input type="text">
        <input type="submit">
    </div>            
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define your style in css like this:

```
body {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
  -webkit-transition: background-color 0.5s ease;
  -moz-transition: background-color 0.5s ease;
  -o-transition: background-color 0.5s ease;
  transition: background-color 0.5s ease;
}

body.active {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```

And then use jQuery just to toggle `.active` class on body

```
$(document).on('click', 'button', function() {
  $('body').toggleClass('active')
  $('.popup').show();
});
```

You have a fully functional example here: http://jsfiddle.net/nb4s4vya/10/

## Edit

I made some small changes to do exactly what you requested in your last comment. Test it here: http://jsfiddle.net/nb4s4vya/18/

Comment: Can you help me to fix it so when I click on the outside of the input element it will bring back the body color?

Comment: Yes, but why is the toggleClass doesn't work well on the button? did you see that?

Comment: I wanted to create it without the 'Close' button, so the users will just click on the background and it will return to the default color, but thanks anyway